# Subclassing widgets in QT designer

Tags: c++, qt

I am having a hard time subclassing Widgets in the QDesigner. I am using QDesigner to create my UI, but using cmake to compile rather than .pro files. So I am basically using QT Creator for nothing other than generating ui files.

Now I want to subclass QLabel in order to override the mouse click event, so as far as I understand all I have to do is right click the QLabel and select "promote to". It then asks me what i want to promote to, so I say "clickable_qlabel.h". However, when I call "make", I get "ui_mainWindow.h:95:5: error: ‘Clickable_QLabel’ does not name a type". Unfortunately I have no idea where I need to put clickable_qlabel.h, or whether it already exists and I just need to fill it with my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks.

[UPDATE]

OK, so now I have created the following class:

QLabelClickable.h

```
#ifndef _QLABELCLICKABLE_H_
#define _QLABELCLICKABLE_H_

#include <QLabel>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class QLabelClickable : public QLabel
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QLabelClickable( const QString& text="", QWidget* parent=0 );
    ~QLabelClickable();
signals:
    void clicked(int, int);
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
};

#endif
```

QLabelClickable.cpp

```
#include "QLabelClickable.h"

QLabelClickable::QLabelClickable(const QString& text, QWidget* parent)
    : QLabel(parent)
{
    setText(text);
}

QLabelClickable::~QLabelClickable()
{
}

void QLabelClickable::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    emit clicked(event->x(),event->y());
}
```

So this code compiles beautifully. So now I am in QtDesigner and I create a QLabel, called label4, and I right click and select "Promote to". Then under "Promoted class name:" I type "QLabelClickable" and under "Header file:" I type "QLabelClickable.h". Then I click "Promote". Wonderful. But I am still getting the error:

```
Vigil/build/ui_mainWindow.h:328:42: error: no matching function for call to ‘QLabelClickable::QLabelClickable(QWidget*&)’ label_4 = new QLabelClickable(tab);
```

So clearly QtDesigner needs to be instructed (somehow) where my implementation of QLabelClickable is. Quite frustrating.

Comment: Firtsly, you must create class that'll be subclass from QLabel. Than you must promote ui's QLabel to your class by typing its name.

Comment: If you permit: why ? You will have much pain compiling your project without qmake, I think...

Comment: @Boiethios Why do you think so? It seems to be all working just fine.

Comment: @MrSquid because of all the messy mocs and so that. Perhaps it is simple, I don't know; but when you make Qt programs from Qt creator, it handles those things for you.

Comment: @Boiethios Well thank you for the advice, I will bear it in mind. However, I haven't had any problems. In fact, the lines: set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
and QT5_WRAP_UI( UI_HDRS ${UI_FILES} ) in my CMakeLists take care of all that for me no problems.

Comment: @MrSquid Oh, that is a very good advice, I did not know. For your issue, you have to promote your widget to a class that inherit from the widget (here, from QLabel) ; and give the file where is your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eh. My error, I should have read the error message properly. I hadn't included a constructor for the passing of only a QWidget. Adding

```
QLabelClickable::QLabelClickable( QWidget* parent ) : QLabel(parent) {

}
```

to my CPP has solved the problem! Hooray.